# Modal Box to appear when user enters any page on website, but not while surfing

Tags: jquery, wordpress, modal-dialog

I have a Modal box that appears on my website. so far so good.

Here's the question. I want the Modal Box to appear on ANY page if the user accesses the site externally. like clicking from a link from an external website, or typing out the URL etc etc.

But I do not want the box to appear when the user is surfing through the website.

So I guess the solution would be to include a conditional that checks if the previous link was a local address? maybe?

how would i go about this?

Code below(using wordpress):

```
<div id="modal">
<div id="heading">
    <img src="<?php get_option_tree('mlogo', $theme_options, true); ?>" alt="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>" />
</div>

<div id="content">
    <?php get_option_tree('disclaimer', $theme_options, true); ?>
</div>
<div id="bottomer">
    <a href="<?php get_option_tree('dis_redirect', $theme_options, true); ?>" class="button red">I disagree</a>

    <a href="#" class="button green close">Continue</a>
</div>
```

jquery reveal

```
$('#modal').reveal({ 
animation: 'fade', 
animationspeed: 600, 
closeonbackgroundclick: false, 
dismissmodalclass: 'close'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var refererLink = document.createElement("a");
    refererLink.href = document.referrer;
    var sitHostName = window.location.hostname;

    if (refererLink.hostname != sitHostName) {
        $('#modal').reveal({
            animation: 'fade',
            animationspeed: 600,
            closeonbackgroundclick: false,
            dismissmodalclass: 'close'
        });
    }
});
```

Ok hear is a completely different answer that uses the referrer in the host header. It will pop up the model when the referrer is not set or doesn't mach your host name. M

Comment: Oh wow that's great!
Is it possible to set the cookie not by time?
i'd like to set it so that whenever a user comes onto the site it still pops up. just only when it's linked externally.

Comment: It should be mention that some privacy add-ons and/or browser settings are capable to remove the informations from `document.referrer`. This technique will, depending on how the `document.referrer` is then set, either never display the popup or always displays it.

Comment: Ye a combination of things is probably called for. Use sessions, cookies and referrer in combination to get the best over all result.